# How to make Vue and Vite work with web components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, custom-element, lit

I want to migrate my **Vue 2** project from webpack to [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/).
And have to use 3rd party web components that built with [lit-element](https://lit.dev/).

Those components throws errors during the runtime (by vue):

> Unknown custom element: < foo-component > - did you register the
> component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
> the "name" option.

And also (by [lit-element](https://lit.dev/))

> Failed to set the 'adoptedStyleSheets' property on 'ShadowRoot':
> Failed to convert value to 'CSSStyleSheet'.

As far as I can see those 3rd party web components do only this in theirs index files (inside `node_modules`):

```js
import FooComponent from './FooComponent';
customElements.define('foo-component', FooComponent);
```

So before (with webpack setup) I just imported them and everything used to work. Well, actually for webpack `lit-scss-loader` was used also for those components.

I assume that Vite perhaps needs some additional configuration, or maybe something similar to "webpack" loader is needed here, but not sure what direction I have to move.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of steps are needed.

Imagine I have 3rd party webcomponents named "foo". So all of them are in `node_modules/@foo`.

I need to do these steps:

1. Tell Vite that all components starting with "foo-" are webcomponents.

   `isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith('foo-')`
2. Add the "[postcssLit](https://github.com/umbopepato/rollup-plugin-postcss-lit)" plugin to help vite prepare the CSS for the webcomponents.
3. Tell Vite how to treat CSS paths for webcomponents.

   `'~@foo': fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules/@foo', import.meta.url))`

Here is the full config:

```
//vite.config.ts

import postcssLit from 'rollup-plugin-postcss-lit';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(
      {
        template: {
          compilerOptions: {
            // 1. Tell Vite that all components starting with "foo-" are webcomponents
            isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith('foo-')
          }
        }
      }
    ),
    vueJsx(),
    // 2. This "postcssLit" plugin helps prepare CSS for the webcomponents
    postcssLit()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // 3. Tell Vite how to treat CSS paths for webcomponents
      '~@foo': fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules/@foo', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Configure [`@vite/plugin-vue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-vue) to ignore Lit elements, e.g., elements starting with `my-lit` in their registered name:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          // treat all components starting with `my-lit` as custom elements
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('my-lit'),
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-lit-in-vue?file=vite.config.js)